# Download attachment using active sync protocol

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

I am able to fetch the mail body & attachment details from server using `Sync` command. Now I am unable to find a way to download the attachment and show in the screen. Below is my `sync` command response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sync xmlns:email="Email:" xmlns:airsyncbase="AirSyncBase:" xmlns:email2="Email2:" xmlns="AirSync:">
  <Collections>
    <Collection>
      <SyncKey>334239291</SyncKey> <CollectionId>5</CollectionId> <Status>1</Status>
       <Commands>
         <Add>
           <ServerId>5:3</ServerId>
           <ApplicationData>
             <email:To>"Device User" &lt;someone1@example.com&gt;</email:To> 
             <email:From>"Device User2" &lt;someone2@example.com&gt;</email:From>              
             <email:Subject>With Attachment</email:Subject> 
             <email:DateReceived>2009-03-04T22:48:41.211Z</email:DateReceived> 
             <email:DisplayTo>Device User</email:DisplayTo>               
             <email:ThreadTopic>With Attachment</email:ThreadTopic> 
             <email:Importance>1</email:Importance>
             <email:Read>0</email:Read> 
             <airsyncbase:Attachments>
               <airsyncbase:Attachment>               
                 <airsyncbase:DisplayName>Test.txt</airsyncbase:DisplayName>      
                 <airsyncbase:FileReference>5%3a3%3a0</airsyncbase:FileReference> 
                 <airsyncbase:Method>1</airsyncbase:Method> 
                 <airsyncbase:EstimatedDataSize>84</airsyncbase:EstimatedDataSize>
               </airsyncbase:Attachment> </airsyncbase:Attachments> 
             <airsyncbase:Body>
               <airsyncbase:Type>1</airsyncbase:Type>                        
               <airsyncbase:EstimatedDataSize>33</airsyncbase:EstimatedDataSize> 
               <airsyncbase:Truncated>1</airsyncbase:Truncated>
             </airsyncbase:Body> 
             <email:Flag /> 
             <email:ContentClass>urn:content-classes:message</email:ContentClass> <airsyncbase:NativeBodyType>1</airsyncbase:NativeBodyType> <email2:ConversationId>¥gÈtent-cl<email2:ConversationId> <email2:ConversationIndex>...<email2:ConversationIndex> <email:Categories />
          </ApplicationData>
        </Add>
      </Commands>
    </Collection>
  </Collections>
</Sync>
￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼
￼￼￼
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download a copy of [[MS-ASCMD]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299441(v=EXCHG.80).aspx). It can answer a lot of your questions about ActiveSync. For attachments, it depends on the version of the protocol you are using. For 12.1 and earlier, you need to use the [GetAttachment command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee218451(v=exchg.80).aspx). For 14.0 and up, you need to use the [ItemOperations command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202415(v=exchg.80).aspx). Here's an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee219747(v=exchg.80).aspx).

Comment: Well i already tried that. My request is
Post : cmd=GetAttachment

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Attachment>
    <DisplayName>[[ReadmefirstExProto]].pdf</DisplayName>
    <FileReference>RgAAAAAJYBeAulyOS5Z0Db%3a0</FileReference>
    <Method>1</Method>
    <EstimatedDataSize>146424</EstimatedDataSize>
</Attachment>

But no luck

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot it's different depending on protocol version. See edited answer.